# Backbone.js able to do rest and localstorage?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, offline, backbone.js

I have been experimenting with the localstorage module for Backbone.js (https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage). As I understand it this overloads Backbone.sync and therefore stops backbone from pushing to the server(?). Ideally, I would like pass my data back to the server as well and persist it locally when online and just use localstorage when offline (you know, the perfect app). I haven't found any documentation yet.

Is Backbone.localStorage a part of this?
Has anyone been able to build this scenario? 
How is this done? (Please tell me I don't have to roll my own.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Backbone.localStorage is an external file you can use which overwrites Backbone.Sync.

You can use simple feature detection for whether the user is offline or online and then asynchronously load Backbone.localStorage.js if they are offline.

If neccesary you can also pass in a specific version of `Backbone.sync` to your models and collections.

If you want to do both at the same time you'll have to write your own version of Backbone.sync that both calls the server and calls localStorage.

The easiest way to do this is to just define

```
Backbone.sync = function() {
    originalSync.apply(this, arguments);
    localStorageSync.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned in the comments, if you use the latest backbone [localStorage plugin](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage) then you can do the following

```
Backbone.sync = function Sync() {
    Backbone.ajaxSync.apply(this, arguments);
    return Backbone.localSync.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: That makes sense. I think having both and then dropping the original when offline makes the most sense (thanks for including it). Have you any personal experience with these scenarios?

Comment: @LeRoy no but having some feature detection around the `originalSync` to check whether your online makes sense. Also make sure to make the real server more "authorative" then the offline storage one. And put a system to monitor changes made when offline and push them as a batch to the server.

Comment: is there any example application I can refer for local storage + offline synch at the same time.

Comment: @Pankaj use the `ononline` event

Comment: Might be worth noting that there are a couple pull requests in the github repo for this plugin that have similar goals: [one](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/pull/9) involves keeping a reference to the original `Backbone.sync` as `Backbone.ajaxSync`, for instance.

Comment: As a follow-up to @pat's note, the [pull request](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/pull/9) was accepted on 2011-12-28. When using the localstorage plugin, `Backbone.sync` stores to local storage, whereas `Backbone.ajaxSync` uses the native `Backbone.sync`.

Comment: Where does that actually go, here is my stackoverflow Question so u can see the code I am working with... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469079/using-backbone-localstorage-and-still-making-calls-to-the-server