# Using Backbone LocalStorage and still making calls to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, backbone-routing

How do I make a call to the server using Backbone localStorage I saw this question, but I am not sure where I apply it?

[Backbone.js able to do rest and localstorage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761349/backbone-js-able-to-do-rest-and-localstorage)

Here is my code for the view:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'models/song',
  //'collections/songs',
  //'views/song',
  'text!templates/search.html'

], function($, _, Backbone, SearchM, SearchT){ //Song, Songs, SongV, 

  var Search = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: SearchM,
    el: $("#Sirius"),
    events: {
      'submit #searchMusic': 'search'
    },
    search: function (search) {
      console.log(SearchM);
      this.model.save({
        channel: this.$el.find('#channel'),
        week: this.$el.find('#week'),
        year: this.$el.find('#year'),
        filter: this.$el.find('#filter')
      });
      console.log('saved');
    },
    render: function () { 
      this.$el.html( SearchT );

    }
  });
    return Search;
});
```

Here is the model:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function(_, Backbone) {

  var Search = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/music'
  });
  return Search;
});
```

this.model.save does not work giving me this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){return r.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'save'
```

I am trying to make an ajax-post to my server at that url.

Comment: So where is backbone.localstorage? `this.model` is a function not an object, instantiate one in your initilize function or provide one in `new Search({model: modelInstance})`

Answer (score 0):

I've got an error because you haven't instantiate your model. Instead

```
 model: SearchM,
```

you should have

```
 model: new SearchM(),
```

Comment: If I do that the page does not load and I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'set' ... I am using require.js and backbone amd if that helps but ya it is getting instantiated I believe, it is just that the .save() might not work because I cannot make ajax calls while using backbone.localstorage as it replaces backbone.sync